# Please explain these Python Fetch types

Tags: python, odoo

What is the difference between these fetching.?
please give me a examples for reference site to get clear idea.still i'm confuse with it

```
res = cr.dictfetchall()

res2 = cr.dictfetchone()

res3 = cr.fetchall()

res4 = cr.fetchone()
```

cr is the current row, from the database cursor  (OPENERP 7 )

ex :

```
def _max_reg_no(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute("""
    select register_no as reg_no
    from bpl_worker
    where id in (select max(id) from bpl_worker)
    """)
    res = cr.fetchone()[0]
    print (res)
    return res
```

Comment: what is `cr` in your example code?

Comment: @olly_uk:
post edited friend

Comment: [There is a complete description of each method in PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`cr.dictfetchall()` will give you all the matching records in the form of ** list of dictionary** containing **key, value**.

`cr.dictfetchone()` works same way as `cr.dictfetchall()` except it returns only single record.

`cr.fetchall()` will give you all the matching records in the form of **list of tupple**.

`cr.fetchone()` works same way as `cr.fetchall()` except it returns only single record.

In your given query, if you use:

1. `cr.dictfetchall()` will give you `[{'reg_no': 123},{'reg_no': 543},]`.
2. `cr.dictfetchone()` will give you `{'reg_no': 123}`.
3. `cr.fetchall()` will give you '[(123),(543)]'.
4. `cr.fetchone()` will give you '(123)'.

Comment: @AnneMary Thanks for the compliment.